How ChatGPT pass from a prompt to a predicted word?
There is something that i can't get it, given a prompt input to ChatGPT, this is One Hot Encoded, Embedded, Positional Encoded and so on. Anyway we have a matrix, still after attention mechanism we have a matrix, how  we end with a probability vector and not with a probability matrix?

Once the last level of the multi-head attention mechanism returns its output, the matrix is flattened in an array and sent as input to a linear level (a.k.a. a fully-connected layer).The output of this layer is activated via Softmax in order to have probabilities associated to the next token. The token with the highest probability is then returned.
